# How to display same star symbol properly in every device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I created a Wordpress website recently and when i use the website on mobile browser(Chrome on Android),'\2605' star symbol is reacting differently.I use '\2605' in css to display group of 5 stars and site shows group of stars according to the value given to a  javascript function.Below is the code for your understanding.

CSS:

```
.rating {
font-size: 48px;
color: #0095f9;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
}
.rating::before { 
content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605\2605" 
}
```

Javascript:

```
function rating( stars ) {
var ratingfill=stars;
var ratingfillshow=stars.toFixed(1);
if(ratingfillshow>0){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ratingfillshow;}
if(ratingfillshow==0){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';}
var rating_integer=Math.floor(ratingfill);
var rating_decimal=ratingfill%1;
var rating_dec_trimmed=rating_decimal.toFixed(1);  
if((rating_dec_trimmed==0.1)||(rating_dec_trimmed==0.2)||
(rating_dec_trimmed==0.3)||(rating_dec_trimmed==0.4))
{window.rate1.style.width = ((40*rating_integer)+18) + 'px';}
if((rating_dec_trimmed==0.6)||(rating_dec_trimmed==0.7)||
(rating_dec_trimmed==0.8)||(rating_dec_trimmed==0.9))
{window.rate1.style.width = ((40*rating_integer)+28) + 'px';}
if(rating_dec_trimmed==0.5)
{window.rate1.style.width = ((40*rating_integer)+20) + 'px';}
if(rating_dec_trimmed==0)
{window.rate1.style.width = (40*rating_integer) + 'px';}
 }
```

In Javascript function rating(stars) is used to change the width of group of stars according to value of stars parameter of function rating(stars).

This works fine if the website works on chrome desktop browser but works in different way if site is used in chrome mobile browser.How to use star symbol in css so that there is no difference between chrome desktop browser and chrome mobile browser?Also how to make star symbol function the same in every browser?Below screenshots will show the difference i was talking about.

Star symbol display in chrome mobile browser when stars value is 2.

[image: Star symbol display in chrome mobile browser when stars value is 2.]

Star symbol display in chrome desktop browser when stars value is 2.

[image: Star symbol display in chrome desktop browser when stars value is 2.]

Thanking in advance.

Comment: the star is a character and would depend on the font-family

Comment: You can use font awesome star for this..See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-star-half-full) example.. Read more about it [here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/star/)...

Comment: @smerny can u elaborate?

Comment: as lal mentioned, use fontawesome or glyphicons or something like that...  force a font family rather than let the browser choose it's default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the stars are a font, that means everything you do in order to get the right width and height for the container depends on the font of the stars.

One possibility would be to give the stars a fixed font size (but the font-family must be identically everywhere of course), screenshot all 5 stars in a row and get the width for one start using photoshop or something, so you know which width 1 star has. If you got that value you can work with these pixel sizes.

A second one would be to do a picture of 5 starts in a row, put them in two containers, the outer one has the width the whole element should have on your website (means if 5 stars are displayed), the second limits the picture, which would mean if you want to show 2 stars, the width of the inner container would be 40%. And of course the inner container has the image in it.